# SQL Retention Rates

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to construct a rolling retention measure but am having troubles figuring how to do it in redshift.

I have defined retention as the intersection between two sets of users. The first a cohort of distinct user ids who 90 days from todays date had been active at least once 30 days from that date (between 90 and 120 days from today). The second is the number of those users who were active in the last 30 days from today.

Retention = Todays 30 day active users who were in original cohort 90 days ago / 30 day active suers 90 days ago

My sessions table looks like this:

| id | created_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-03-04 |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 |
| 1 | 2020-12-15 |
| 2 | 2021-02-17 |

The only way I can seem to do this is as follows:

1. Create a temple table and insert into for todays date.

```
with t1 as (
    select distinct customer_id id
    from sessions
    and created_date >= dateadd('day', -29, current_date)
    )
, t2 as (
    select distinct customer_id id
    from sessions
    and created_date <= dateadd('day', -89, current_date) 
    and created_date >= dateadd('day', -119, current_date)
    )
select current_date, 
    count(t1.id) as original, 
    count(t2.id) as current,
    round(cast(count(t2.id) as float) / cast(count(t1.id) as float), 2) as ratio
into temp table temp1
from t1
left join t2
on t1.id = t2.id
```

2. Run an insert statement into the temp table multiple times subtracting one day from current date in each query

```
insert into temp1
with t1 as (
    select distinct customer_id id
    from sessions 
    and created_date >= dateadd('day', -29, current_date-1)
    )
, t2 as (
    select distinct customer_id id
    from sessions
    and created_date <= dateadd('day', -89, current_date-1) 
    and created_date >= dateadd('day', -119, current_date-1)
    )
select current_date-1,  
    count(t1.id) as original, 
    count(t2.id) as current,
    round(cast(count(t2.id) as float) / cast(count(t1.id) as float), 2) as ratio
from t1
left join t2
on t1.id = t2.id
```

3. Obtain this table with a daily retention rate for all days so far in 2021

The column original is the user cohort of 30 day active users 90 days ago from the reference date.
The current column is the number of users from the cohort in the original column that are 30 day active users at the reference date.

Step 1 returns only the first row 2021-03-05 and step 2 gives me the other row.

| date | original | current | ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-05 | 100 | 70 | 0.7 |
| 2021-03-04 | 100 | 60 | 0.6 |

This process obviously is very inefficient and I am trying to figure out whether there is faster, easier way to do it? The issue is I need to compare a distinct user cohort from 3 months ago and then see today how many of those users from the cohort are still active.

All hep will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't follow the question.  It is all about "today's date", but then you are talking about historical dates as well.  And then there is this statement:  "who 90 from todays date who had been active at least once in the last 30 days".  90 days or 30 days?

Comment: Hi Gordon, at todays date (5 March 2021) I need to look 90 days into the past and find the number of users at that point (6 December 2020) how many were 30 day active users from that date. Lets say there are 100 at that date, I then want to know how many of that cohort are 30 day actives at todays date. Lets say there are 70, so 70%. I have a working query for this but I also need yesterday and the day. Basically the calculation needs to be repeated everyday for the last year.

Comment: Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the number of users for 30 days today and 90 days ago for each date, the query is:

```sql
with t1 as (
  select
    s2.created_date,
    count(distinct customer_id id) as cnt30
  from sessions s1 inner join
    (select distinct created_date from sessions) s2
    on dateadd('day', -29, s2.created_date)<=s1.created_date
       and s1.created_date<=s2.created_date
  group by s2.created_date
)
select a1.current_date, 
  a1.cnt30 as original, 
  a2.cnt32 as current,
  round(cast(a2.cnt30) as float) / cast(count(a1.cnt30) as float), 2) as ratio
from t1 as a1 inner join t1 as a2
  on dateadd('day', -89, a1.created_date)=a2.created_date
order by 1
```

Using the subquery in the select-list, the query is:

```sql
with t1 as (
  select
    s2.created_date,
    (select count(distinct s1.customer_id) from sessions s1
     where dateadd('day', -29, s2.created_date)<=s1.created_date
       and s1.created_date<=s2.created_date) as cnt30
  from
    (select distinct created_date from sessions) s2
)
select a1.current_date, 
  a1.cnt30 as original, 
  a2.cnt32 as current,
  round(cast(a2.cnt30) as float) / cast(count(a1.cnt30) as float), 2) as ratio
from t1 as a1 inner join t1 as a2
  on dateadd('day', -89, a1.created_date)=a2.created_date
order by 1
```

First, use joins and subqueries to calculate the number of unique IDs for the last 30 days on each date.
Next, join the same tables and output the number of unique IDs on the current day and 90 days ago.

*Note taht I've never used redshift, so I'll write this based on your query and common SQL syntax. I hope my answer helps you.*